# JS - How to get the correct val of a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On load I create a map, the key is an anker-element and the value the offset of that anker. Unfortunately I cannot read out the val correctly, it always returns the value of the last key. What is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1c4h17ma/)

HTML

```
<a>Anker</a><a>Anker</a><a>Anker</a>
```

JS

```
var ankers = {};
$('a').each(function(){

var pos = $(this).offset().left;

ankers[$(this)] = pos;
});

$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(ankers[$(this)]);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript objects, which you're using for a map here only support string keys (like objects in most other languages).

If you want an actual map should use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object instead if you'd like to use an object key - but those only work in new browsers, you can ([polyfill it though](https://github.com/medikoo/es6-map)):

```
var ankers = new Map();
$('a').each(function(){

    var pos = $(this).offset().left;

    ankers.set($(this), pos);
});

$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(ankers.get($(this));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vykhj1de/) (based on dfsq's)

Alternatively, you can use the element's ID as a key and give them IDs. Or, you can avoid this altogether and save the data on the objects rather than in a map:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).data("anker", $(this).offset().left);
});

$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).data("anker");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s15w6bfe/)

You should only use data attributes for presentation properties and binding, but this seems to be appropriate and is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

The property of the object in javascript is always a String. So when you try to set a map with an object as a key, this object is converted to string type. As the result you have only `ankers` object has only one key `[object Object]`.

Instead consider to give an ids to anchors and use something like this:

```
var ankers = {};
$('a').each(function () {
    var pos = $(this).offset().left;
    ankers[this.id] = pos;
});

$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.val').val(ankers[this.id]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/1c4h17ma/1/